# Show that at least half of all graphs on n vertices are connected.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I am following a course on Combinatorial Optimization and the question is: Show that at least half of all graphs on n vertices are connected. I have a really hard time understanding and answering questions like this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing really, I do not know where to start.

Comment: Maybe use induction on the number of vertices?

Comment: Have you verified it for, say, $n\leq 4$? That's a pretty obvious thing to go for if you're stuck. Seing as there are $1024$ different graphs on $4$ vertices (assuming the vertices are distinguishable), it may pay off to try to be systematic in some way. Maybe you find a system which is generalizable to larger $n$. Maybe that system uses what you've already calculated for $n = 1, 2, 3$, and in that case induction might be a good way to go.

Comment: How do I now the number of graphs on n vertices?

Comment: Running before you can walk, here? If you don't know how to count the number of graphs, how do you expect to know what "at least half" means? Why are you attempting this problem without first searching out what is probably prerequisite knowledge?

Comment: I have looked it up before, but I cannot find how there are 1024 graphs on 4 vertices, since others state it is 2^(n*(n-1)/2). You are true about the running before walking thing, but I just find it very hard to get started with the proofs

Comment: You're right. I was one off on the 1024 thing; there are 1024 graphs on 5 vertices. It is, of course, 64 graphs on 4 vertices, as you say. Still, if you want to count how many of them are connected and how many aren't, it might pay off to be systematic. And getting started with a proof does not mean writing the first three sentences of a finished proof. It means experimenting and testing, trying out different things until you happen to stumble upon a connection you can exploit.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n$ be the number of graohs on $n$ vertices and $B_n$ the number of connected such graphs, and $C_n:=\frac{B_n}{A_n}$. The claim is that $C_n\ge\frac 12$.

Clearly, $A_n=2^{n-1}A_{n-1}$ (a graph on $n$ vertices is obtained from a graph on $n-1$ vertices by perhaps adding edges from vertex $n$ to other vertices).
Similarly, $$B_n\ge (2^{n-1}-1)B_{n-1}$$ (at least one edge from vertex $n$ to a connected graph on $n-1$ vertices produces a connected graph). Hence $C_n\ge\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)C_{n-1}$ -- which is unfortuneatle not yet good enough: From $C_1=1$, we find from this $C_2\ge\frac12$, but only $C_3\ge \frac38$. A manual count gives us the correct value $C_3=\frac12$.

For $n\ge 4$, we can also obtain a connected graph by

- picking one of the old $n-1$ vertices and connecting vertex $n$ to it
- picking a connected graph on the remaining $n-2$ $(>1)$ vertices
- adding at least one of the edges from $n$ to this

in $(n-1)\cdot(2^{n-2}-1)\cdot B_{n-2}$ ways.

This gives us the better bound
$$B_n\ge(2^{n-1}-1)B_{n-1}+(n-1)\cdot (2^{n-2}-1)B_{n-2}\qquad\text{for }n\ge 4. $$
So for $n\ge 4$,
$$ \begin{align}C_n&\ge\frac{(2^{n-1}-1)B_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}A_{n-1}}+\frac{(n-1)(2^{n-2}-1)B_{n-2}}{2^{n-1}2^{n-2}A_{n-2}}\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)C_{n-1}+\frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-2}}\right)C_{n-2}\\
&>\left(1-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\cdot \frac12+\frac1{2^{n-1}}\cdot \frac12\\
&=\frac12\end{align}$$
and the claim follows by induction.